# How to use DataTable without jQuery

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to use [DataTable](https://datatables.net). In this regard I have below JavaScript function.

```
 (function () {
    const getOrderInformationData = async (container) => {
      const response = await mdcRequestData("/product/information-table/go2wire");
      if (response && response.data.length > 0) {
        container.innerHTML = mdcProcessData(response.data, "orderDataTemplate");

        new DataTable("#order_information");

      } else {
        container.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">No product information was found.</div>';
      }
    };
    const orderDataContainer = document.getElementById("order_information");
    if (orderDataContainer) {
      getOrderInformationData(orderDataContainer);
    }
})();
```

But I am getting error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: DataTable is not defined`.

How to use DataTable without jQuery ?

Comment: DataTables requires jQuery. If you want to use something like that without jQuery, rewrite it or find a different library.

Comment: ...such as https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables

Answer (score 2):

[Our website is using Datatables with Svelte](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/trading-pairs).

While Datatables internally depends on jQuery, you load jQuery without needing to use it with the rest of your website. You can also pass a DOM element to Datatables and make it mount on any DOM element.

Here is an example using ECMAScript 6 modules. Understanding of advanced JavaScript loading techniques and package management is needed in order to install Datatables via NPM.

> Render dynamic tables using server-side sorting and filtering
> using DataTables library.   While the DataTables is settings up
> itself, server a skeleton loader.
> https://datatables.net/manual/index
> The CSS files generated with
> the Datatables bundler:       https://datatables.net/download/
> Use `npm install --save datatables.net-bs4`
> and `npm install --save datatables.net-responsive-bs4`

```js
<script lang="ts">
// https://svelte.dev/repl/a4684fe5be9a4c63963bb128c4adf056?version=3.23.2
    import { browser } from '$app/env';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import datatableModule from 'datatables.net-dt';
    // DataTables CSS
    import 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css';
    import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.css';

    // Is DataTables initialised
    let loaded = false;
    let el, table; // table element, table object (API)
    let extraClass = clickableRows ? 'clickable' : '';
        
    onMount(async () => {
        if (browser) {
            const DataTable = datatableModule();
            let _options = options || {};
            _options['columns'] = columns;
            let table = new DataTable(el, _options);
            table.draw();
            console.log('DataTable loaded');
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML markup

```html
<div class="datatables-wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table
            bind:this={el}
            class={'table table-datatable ' + extraClass}
            style={loaded ? 'display: table; width: 100%;' : 'display: none'}
            data-cy={dataCy || 'exchange-table'}
        >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {#each columns as column}
                        <th>{column.name}</th>
                    {/each}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody />
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="data-tables-skeleton" 
         style={!loaded ? 'display: block' : 'display: none'}>
        <Skeleton layout="full" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[See full source code](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/src/lib/datatable/datatable.svelte).

Answer (score 0):

Converting a [comment suggesting simple-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72676143/how-to-use-datatable-without-jquery#comment128374255_72676143) to an answer:

```js
new window.simpleDatatables.DataTable("#demo-table");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@9.0.0"></script>
<table id="demo-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ext.</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th data-type="date" data-format="YYYY/DD/MM">Start Date</th>
      <th>Completion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Pugh</td>
      <td>9958</td>
      <td>Curicó</td>
      <td>2005/02/11</td>
      <td>37%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theodore Duran</td>
      <td>8971</td>
      <td>Dhanbad</td>
      <td>1999/04/07</td>
      <td>97%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kylie Bishop</td>
      <td>3147</td>
      <td>Norman</td>
      <td>2005/09/08</td>
      <td>63%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code above is excerpted from simple-datatables' [CDN example](https://fiduswriter.github.io/simple-datatables/demos/3-cdn/).